# WPF: Image in ListView is not be shown

Tags: wpf, image, listview, binding

I have a ListView which should contain per line an image and text. The binding of the text works fine, but the image is not be shown.

My XAML-Markup:

```
<ListView Name="lvUpgrade">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Width="20px">
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Path=Icon}" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
            <GridViewColumn Width="75px" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Time, StringFormat={}{0:HH:mm:ss}}" />
            <GridViewColumn Width="300px" Header="Nachricht" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Message}" />
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

My code behind:

```
Public Class Upgrade

    Public Sub AddMessage(ByVal message As Message)
        Me.lvUpgrade.Items.Add(message)
    End Sub

    Public Class Message

        Public Enum MessageType

            Normal
            Information
            Warning
            [Error]
        End Enum

        Public Sub New(ByVal type As MessageType, ByVal message As String)
            _Type = type
            _Message = message
        End Sub

        Private _Type As MessageType = MessageType.Normal
        Public ReadOnly Property Type As MessageType
            Get
                Return _Type
            End Get
        End Property

        Private _Message As String = String.Empty
        Public ReadOnly Property Message As String
            Get
                Return _Message
            End Get
        End Property

        Private _Time As DateTime = Now
        Public ReadOnly Property Time As DateTime
            Get
                Return _Time
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Icon As System.Drawing.Image
            Get
                Select Case Me.Type
                    Case MessageType.Information
                        Return My.Resources.Information16
                    Case MessageType.Warning
                        Return My.Resources.Alert16
                    Case MessageType.Error
                        Return My.Resources.Error16
                    Case Else
                End Select

                Return Nothing
            End Get
        End Property
    End Class
End Class
```

To bind the image I use a property which returns the image from the local resources. I use the same way to bind the image to the control like I do it for the text. Is this try wrong or why does it not works?

Thanks for any response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to Convert the `Image` to a `BitmapImage`:

For this you could define the following Extension in a separate Module.
This offers the opportunity to use the Function on every Image you will have in your code:

```
Module Extensions

  <Extension()>
  Public Function ToBitmapImage(ByVal lBitmap As Bitmap) As BitmapImage
    Dim lMemoryStream As New MemoryStream()
    Dim lBitmapImage As New BitmapImage()

    lBitmap.Save(lMemoryStream, ImageFormat.Png)
    lBitmapImage.BeginInit()
    lBitmapImage.StreamSource = New MemoryStream(lMemoryStream.ToArray())
    lBitmapImage.EndInit()
    Return lBitmapImage
  End Function

End Module
```

After that you have to edit your property like:

```
Public ReadOnly Property Icon As BitmapImage
  Get
    Select Case Me.Type
      Case MessageType.Information
        Return My.Resources.Information16.ToBitmapImage
      Case MessageType.Warning
        Return My.Resources.Alert16.ToBitmapImage
      Case MessageType.Error
        Return My.Resources.Error16.ToBitmapImage
      Case Else
    End Select

    Return Nothing
  End Get
End Property
```

Comment: That works. Thanks a lot. A hint: the return type of the property also has to be changed to BitmapImage.

Comment: oh, just forgot to change that. Edited that, thanks for the info.